# pymysql only detecting changes made externally after instantiating a new connection

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to run a Python script which leaves a connection open permanently, and responds to changes made outside of the script.

So for example:

1. Data script: Accepts form posts and commits form data to the database
2. Worker script: Monitors the database for new form posts and takes action accordingly

The relevant code in the worker script is:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='dbuser', passwd='dbpass', db='my_db')

def processForms(Formdat):
    c = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    myform.sendEmail(c)
    conn.commit()
    c.close()

def doForms():
    while True:
        ... get data and store in 'myforms' ...
        futures = [executor.submit(processForms, myform) for myform in myforms]
        time.sleep(30)

doForms()
```

Now I don't understand why this is not picking up new forms... If I create a new connection in each iteration of doForms(), the new forms are picked up, but I don't want to be creating and destroying connections all the time.

For example, this modification works:

```
conn = None

def doForms():
    while True:
        global conn
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mw_py')
        ... get data and store in 'myforms' ...
        futures = [executor.submit(processForms, myform) for myform in myforms]
        conn.close()
        time.sleep(30)
```

Is there a way for me to use the open connection and have it poll the latest data?

Comment: Is there specific reason to use pymysql instead of mysql.connector, the official MySQL Python interface?

Comment: @peroksid I couldn't get mysql.connector working with Python3.

Comment: I am working with mysql-connector-python==1.0.12

Answer (score 0):

Open 1 connection in the beginning of your script. It is not a cheap operation to connect.

Remember ID of last row fetched.

On every iteration select rows with ID greater than last seen.

Comment: I was just opening one connection in my original code sample.  Even just a simple SELECT query of "SELECT * FROM myforms WHERE email_sent = False" does not return any results from after the script was instantiated, however if I abort the script and start it again, it correctly identifies the unprocessed forms.

Comment: I doubt you've isolated problematic code in the published snippet.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with transactions isolation or something else.

Comment: It is strange - any action that I perform inside of the web app (such as updating user details) is correctly and immediately reflected in the database and visible in the web app.  The problem only occurs in any changes I make outside of the web app.  I never thought of transaction isolation, so I Googled it and found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/qLHP3iYz8Lo

Comment: It appears it may be an inherent problem with pymysql after all.  This other article seems to suggest setting conn.autocommit(True) to fix the issue (untested), but then again every insert I perform is immediately followed by a .commit(), and it's correctly inserted into the table.  Maybe something to do with conn.autocommit(False) (the default) maintaining a shadow copy. I'll try autocommit(True) by default, as there's only one place I need transactions https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/76

Comment: Well that worked!  Setting autocommit(True) appears to have fixed the problem with reads.  Very strange, I was of the impression commit only affected writing a transaction, not reads... problem with pymysql?  I'll look at mysql-connector-python again! Thanks @peroksid